# Repeat texture to loop around with clip()

Tags: javascript, animation, math, 2d

I have a texture which I use `drawImage()` over a clipping plane. But i have an issue where by I can't figure out how to wrap it around once it's moved more than the width of the texture so it loops indefinitely, it also does not clip for some reason.

My draw code looks like this:

```
var radius = 120;
var pos = {'x':canvas.width/2,'y':canvas.height/2};
var x = 0;
var offsetX = 0;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    x += 1.1415;  

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.clip();

var scale = (radius * 2) / img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, pos.x+x, pos.y, img.width, img.height, pos.x - radius - offsetX * scale, pos.y - radius, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
    ctx.restore();    

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

I have created the demo here so you can see what happens when the texture moves too far, it basically disappears and i need it to loop again without a gap between so its seamless: **http://jsfiddle.net/dv2r8zpv/**

What is the best way to draw the texture's position so it will wrap around, i don't quite understand how to do it.

Comment: Fiddle link is broken

Comment: @Kelv.Gonzales fixed though for some reason you have to click run for it to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a seamless loop now. The code I change are below. Changing the y on drawImage encapsulates the whole circle

```
if (x > img.width) {
    x = 0;
}

ctx.drawImage(img, x, 0, ...);

ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width+x,0, ...);
```

[Updated answer with full circle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv2r8zpv/9/)

Comment: It's not suppose to suddenly jump and start again it's mean to seamlessly repeat so you would see the first letter straight after the last letter. So at some point you will see the same image twice.

Comment: I have modified it now.

Comment: thank you :) just curious if you might know why the clip doesn't seem to fill the entire circle ?